# Navigate to new page in same window

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to click a button and navigate to a new page, not make a second window appear over top of the first window. The pages are the view of complex code (e.g., the actual game). I don't really want to use a navigation window because i don't want forward and back arrows appearing. The error on the code below is that "ns" (NavigationService) is null. How do I make want I want to do work?

```
private void btnLevelDesigner_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    NavigationService ns = NavigationService.GetNavigationService(this);
    LevelDesignerPage levelDesignerPage = new LevelDesignerPage();
    ns.Navigate(levelDesignerPage);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you host the page(s) in a Frame? I can't see a reason for which the above snippet should open a new window instead showing the new page.

Comment: It doesn't open anything as ns is null. I just said i don't want to open a new window to explain what i want. There is no frame. Thanks.

Comment: What I asked you is right what you marked as an answer. If you need a paging-navigation base, you must either host a "Page" inside a Frame (which offers a navigation service), or create a WPF paged-application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would insert a Frame into your main window - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.frame.aspx

This Frame has NavigationService property that allows you to change content of the frame. It should be also available to acces the navigation service from inside content of the frame.

Regarding the Back/forward arrows - Take a look at [ShowNavigationUI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationwindow.showsnavigationui.aspx) Property

Comment: Thanks! I used the NavigationWindow method and deleted the forward/back arrows. This look is about the same as using a frame? (new pic in question edit). Seems perfect. Thank you!

Comment: I haven't made the next page yet so it shows blank, but i can tell it works

Comment: The look should be the same - or at least they both can be configured to be completely invisible (not the content, but border, margin, padding ...)