# How do I open page in different frame - WPF

Tags: wpf, frames

I have 2 frames in a WPF C# window. Upon loading, the application loads a page into the left frame and nothing into the right frame. After navigating through 2 pages in the left frame I am trying to get a different page to load in the right frame. The only way I have been able to do this is to close the window and reload it.

How can I load a new page in the right frame of a WPF window upon a button click on a different page in the left frame on the same WPF window without reloading the hole window?

Thank You

**edit:**

To clarify a bit, I have 1 Window with 2 frames. I want to open a page in the right frame by clicking a button on a page in the left frame. This is what I have:

variables class holding a "test" int:

```
    public static class variables
    {
        public static int test;
    }
```

Main Window:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        int mytest = variables.test;
        left1 left1 = new left1();
        left.NavigationService.Navigate(left1);
        Right1 right1 = new Right1();
        if (mytest == 1)
        {
            right.NavigationService.Navigate(right1);
            MessageBox.Show("1");
        }
    }
```

And the left1 page:

```
 public left1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int test = 1;
        variables.test = test;
        MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
        mw.Show();
    }
```

This works BUT it opens another window on calling mw.Show(); Is there a way for this to work without opening another window (like refreshing the window)? I tried mw.InitializeComponent(); and that would show the MessageBox but would not re render the MainWindow. I have tried to create a Method within MainWindow and call that on the left1 page button click but it does the same thing ... shows the MessageBox but does not refresh the MainWindow.

Comment: check here looks like same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19462474/navigate-to-new-page-in-same-window-wpf

Comment: check this too..http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8548b916-7161-4ca6-876d-212360c2c9fb/how-to-open-window-inside-frame?forum=wpf

Comment: Thank You for looking at this. I updated my situation above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK if you havent figured it out Im new! ... I have many years ago learned Basic, Pascal, and C. And then did some web developing 10 years ago, but its been a long time. I figured it out!! I have only been working with C# WPF for about 2 weeks now.

I bound the Visibility property of the right frame to a method under the MainWindow class which is called on a button click and used INotifyPropertyChanged Event. This is what I have now:

MainWindow.xmal.cs:

```
    public class Refresh : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string vis1;
    public string Vis1
    {
        get { return vis1; }
        set
        {
            if (vis1 != value)
            {
                vis1 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Vis1");
            }
        }
    }
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyname)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private static Refresh Visi;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Left1 l1 = new Left1();
        Right1 r1 = new Right1();
        left.NavigationService.Navigate(l1);
        right.NavigationService.Navigate(r1);
        Visi = new Refresh { Vis1 = "Hidden" };
        DataContext = Visi;
    } 
    public static void showRight()
    {
        Visi.Vis1 = "Visible";
    }
}
```

The XAML:

```
<Frame x:Name="right" Content="Frame" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="224" Margin="262,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="225" Visibility="{Binding Vis1}" />
```

And just a simple button click event on the Left page!:

```
    public partial class Left1 : Page
{
    public Left1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainWindow.showRight();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone else out there! Only took me a day and a half to figure it out! LOL My first successful binding.

So now in this code the right frame has a page loaded but is hidden from view and the left frames page is shown. When the button is clicked on the left page the right frame becomes unhidden!

Answer (score 0):

For opening an other page in WPF by means of the ClickEvent event, you must initialize the navigation services.  Let's have a look on my wpf-app code: I open page 2 on the click event of the button that button is present on page 1:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    NavigationWindow _navigationWindow = new NavigationWindow();

    _navigationWindow.Height = this.Height;

    _navigationWindow.Width = this.Width;

    _navigationWindow.Show();

    _navigationWindow.Navigate(new Page2());

    this.Close();


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void Login_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    NavigationWindow _navigationWindow = new NavigationWindow();

    _navigationWindow.Height = this.Height;

    _navigationWindow.Width = this.Width;

    _navigationWindow.Show();

    _navigationWindow.Navigate(new Page1());


    this.Close();
}
```